# Chrome Developer Tools does not let me edit CSS due to bug

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Any new CSS code starts with a :, therefore I cannot complete the code. I have tried reinstalling Chrome, to no avail. How do I get rid of this bug?

I don't have 10 reputation so I cannot attach images to this post. Would have made life easier, but oh well.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are doing. What is "any new CSS code"? A stylesheet? A rule? A property? A value? Sharing a screenshot at http://img.ur would help a lot.

Comment: You can probably post a link to an image, can't you?